# How to get the size of bitmap after displaying it in ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-imageview, bitmapimage

I have a imageview

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCaptured"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/captured_image" />
```

I capture a image from camera, converted that image into bitmap.

```
Bitmap thumbnail;
thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity()
                    .getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

when i get the resolution of this bitmap before displaying it in my above imageview, like

```
Log.i("ImageWidth = " + thumbnail.getWidth(), "ImageHeight = "
                + thumbnail.getHeight());
```

its returning me `ImageWidth = 2592  ImageHeight = 1936`

after this i displayed this bitmap in my above imageview as `imgCaptured.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);`  then i go size of my imageview as

```
Log.i("ImageView Width = " + imgCaptured.getWidth(),
                "ImageView Height = " + imgCaptured.getHeight());
```

this returned me `ImageView Width = 480  ImageView Height = 720`

**now my question is that**

- How can i get the size of that bitmap **after** displaying it in my imageview.
  I know this can be done by using this

  ```
  image.buildDrawingCache();
  Bitmap bmap = image.getDrawingCache();
  ```

  but this will create a new bitmap of size equal to that of imageview.
- I also want to know that, Does image resized automatically after displaying it in the imageview. if yes then is there any way to display the image in imageview without resizing the image.

**Edit**

Actually i have captured an image of 2592x1936. I displayed this image in my imageView, did some other operations on this image . now i want to save this image with same 2592x1936 resolution. is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify-  you mean the size of the bitmap in the image view?  If you have no padding, the two are equivalent, and the width/height of the ImageView is the width/height of the bitmap.  If you have padding, just subtract it out.

Comment: yes i mean the size of bitmap after displaying it in the imageview.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Actually i have captured an image of 2592x1936. I displayed this image in my imageView, did some other operations on this image . now i want to save this image with same 2592x1936 resolution. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but maybe not at full quality.  If you shrunk the image (without keeping the full size version around), you lost data in shrinking it and Android will be guessing at what the data is when it expands it.  If you manipulated the full size version, its rather easy-  just use the compress() function on the bitmap class with a FileOutputStream.

Comment: thanks for replying Can you paste a code please, for retrieving the full sized image from the imageview with 2592x1936 size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After you display a `Bitmap` in a `ImageView`, The `ImageView` will create a BitmapDrawable object to draw it in ImageView's Canvas. So you can invoke `ImageView.getDrawable()` method to get the reference of the `BitmapDrawable`, and get the Bounds by invoke `Drawable.getBounds(Rect rect`) method. through the bounds, you can compute the width and height of the Bitmap drawn in `ImageView`

```
Drawable drawable = ImageView.getDrawable();
//you should call after the bitmap drawn
Rect bounds = drawable.getBounds();
int width = bounds.width();
int height = bounds.height();
int bitmapWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(); //this is the bitmap's width
int bitmapHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(); //this is the bitmap's height
```

Comment: this error is coming up. The method getBounds() in the type Drawable is not applicable for the arguments (Rect)

Comment: i was making scaleType="fitXY" for my imageview. i removed this, now its working fine. thank you very much

Comment: please tell me how can i save this image with this original resolution of 2592x1936?

Comment: like Quadir said that, you should be careful "scaleType" attribute. Because it changes imageview's height.