# How to get width of what image really occupies on the ImageView android

Tags: android, view, android-activity, bitmap, imageview

I have an activity which only has an ImageView on it. I'm setting an image bitmap for this view that is much taller than wider. So, for example, my activity has 720x950 and my image is 918x2077. 
When I add the image in the imageView, both side parts of imageView stays white (read: no image in there).

If I call mImage.getWidth() it returns me the width of the entire imageView of 720 (which is the activity wide).
I would like to get the width of the image in specific, not of the view.. is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the size of bitmap after displaying it in ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128204/how-to-get-the-size-of-bitmap-after-displaying-it-in-imageview)

Comment: I took a look at this question, thanks for pointing it out.. However what I wanted is different from what this question covers.. I implemented the solution of this question on my project but it returns me the width and height of the image before the scale to fit on the image view. In my case, for example, it returns me 918x2077.. which is the width and height of the original image. @Gil solution returns me the answer I was looking for, it returns the width of the image after the scale to fit in the image view. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the aspect ratio of your image is being kept. You want to know how much width the image is actually occupying.

You can calculate it!

if your bitmap is 918x2077 and your window size is 720x950, then to calculate your width, simply do:

(950/2077) * 918 = 419.8844...

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks man! What you say is right!! worked like a charm. Sorry for the late response I was doing it wrongly, now i've found the way to go! :)