# Get the Height and the Width of drawn area of an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, size, android-canvas

if I have an ImageView of (800*800 pixels). When I try to draw a line outside this ImageView it draws

```
    myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800,800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    myPaint = new Paint();
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    myCanvas.drawLine(-100, -100, 600, 600, myPaint);
```

this draw my line even if the start point is outside,

Now I want to obtain their total size, I mean [900 , 900]. I don't know from which component can I obtain it (`myCanvas` or `myBitmap` or `myImageView`).

I hope that my question is clear.

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128204/how-to-get-the-size-of-bitmap-after-displaying-it-in-imageview

Comment: No I saw this and when using `myImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()` and `myImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()`, it gives me `800 X 800`

Comment: What do `myCanvas.getWidth()` and `myCanvas.getHeight()` give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what is drawn outside your `bitmap` is lost, and you can check this by rotating your `ImageView`, you will see that what was outside your `bitmap` is **black** even if you drew ther.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you require is :

Using `ImageView.getDrawable().getInstrinsicWidth()` and `getIntrinsicHeight()` will both return the original dimensions.

The only way to get the actual dimensions of the displayed image is by extracting and using the transformation Matrix used to display the image as it is shown. This must be done after the measuring stage and the example here shows it called in an `Override` of `onMeasure()` for a custom `ImageView`:

```
    public class SizeAwareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SizeAwareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Get image matrix values and place them in an array
        float[] f = new float[9];
        getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

        // Extract the scale values using the constants (if aspect ratio maintained, scaleX == scaleY)
        final float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        final float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

        // Get the drawable (could also get the bitmap behind the drawable and getWidth/getHeight)
        final Drawable d = getDrawable();
        final int origW = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int origH = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

        // Calculate the actual dimensions
        final int actW = Math.round(origW * scaleX);
        final int actH = Math.round(origH * scaleY);
    }
}
```

**Note:** To get the image transformation Matrix from code in general (like in an Activity), the function is ImageView.getImageMatrix() - e.g. myImageView.getImageMatrix()

Comment: This also give me 800X800

Comment: @RiadSaadi Do you want to find the dimensions of the image formed including the outline?

Comment: Yes I want the size off all drawn area. if for example I draw another line (10,10) to (1000,1000) I will have from (-100,-100) to (1000,1000) which gives width = 1100 and height = 1100

Comment: I am so sorry but even this it gives the original size 800X800,